# Prove $|z_1/z_2| = |z_1|/|z_2|$ without using the polar form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Prove $|z_1/z_2| = |z_1|/|z_2|$ without using the polar form.

Let $z_1 = a_1+b_1i$, $z_2 = a_2+b_2i$. Then
$|z_1| = \sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}$ and $|z_2| = \sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}$. Hence
$$RHS = \frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|} = \frac{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}}$$
$$LHS = \left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right| = 
\left|\frac{(a_1+b_1i)(a_2-b_2i)}{a_2^2-b_2^2}\right| = 
\left|\frac{a_1a_2+b_1b_2}{a_2^2-b_2^2} + i\frac{a_2b_1 - a_1b_2}{a_2^2-b_2^2}\right| \\= 
\frac{\sqrt{a_1^2a_2^2+b_1^2b_2^2+a_2^2b_1^2-a_1^2b_2^2}}{a_2^2-b_2^2}.$$
I'm stuck. Help please.

No polar because this is presented in the context of absolute value and before polar form.

Comment: Hint : use polar form.

Comment: @C.Dubussy This part is discuss before polar form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had some wrong signs

\begin{align*}|\frac{z_1}{z_2}| & = |\frac{(a_1+b_1i)(a_2-b_2i)}{a_2^2\color{red}{+}b_2^2}|\\ &  = |\frac{a_1a_2+b_1b_2}{a_2^2+b_2^2} + i\frac{a_2b_1 - a_1b_2}{a_2^2+b_2^2}|\\ & = \frac{\sqrt{a_1^2a_2^2+b_1^2b_2^2+a_2^2b_1^2\color{red}{+}a_1^2b_2^2}}{a_2^2+b_2^2}
\\ & =\frac{\sqrt{(a_1^2+b_1^2)(a_2^2+b_2^2)}}{a_2^2+b_2^2}
\\ & =\frac{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}}
\end{align*}
As claimed

Answer (score 2):

> $|\frac{1}{z}|=\frac{1}{|z|}$

in fact :
$z=a+ib$ so $|z|^2=a^2+b^2$ and $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{a+ib}=\frac{a-ib}{(a-ib)(a+ib)}=\frac{a-ib}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}(a-ib)$
then :
$$
|\frac{1}{z}|^2= (\frac{1}{a^2+b^2})^2(a^2+b^2)=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{1}{|z|^2}
$$

> |zw|=|z||w|

$z=a+ib$ and $w=c+id$ so $|z|^2=a^2+b^2$ and $|w|^2=c^2+d^2$ 
$zw=(a+ib)(c+id)=ac-bd+i(ac+bd)$
then :
$$
|zw|^2= (ac-bd)^2+(bc+ad)^2= (ac)^2+(db)^2+(bc)^2+(ad)^2=a^2(c^2+d^2)+b^2(c^2+d^2)=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=|z|^2|w|^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the left hand side, you may rather write
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right|&=\left|\frac{(a_1+b_1i)(a_2-b_2i)}{a_2^2+b_2^2}\right|
\\\\&=\frac{\sqrt{(a_1a_2+b_1b_2)^2+(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)^2}}{a_2^2+b_2^2}
\\\\&=\frac{\sqrt{a^2_1a^2_2+a_1^2b^2_2+a^2_2b^2_1+b^2_1b^2_2}}{a_2^2+b_2^2}
\\\\&=\frac{\sqrt{(a^2_1+b^2_1)(a^2_2+b^2_2)}}{a_2^2+b_2^2}
\\\\&=\frac{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Check your signs on your last line...

$\dfrac {|z_1 \bar z_2|}{|z_2\bar z_2|} = \dfrac {\sqrt{a_1^2a_2^2 + a_1^2b_2^2+a_2^2b_1^2 + b_1^2b_2^2}}{a_2^2+b_2^2}\\
\dfrac {\sqrt{a_1^2(a_2^2 +b_2^2) + b_1^2(a_2^2 + b_2^2)}}{a_2^2+b_2^2}\\
\dfrac {\sqrt{(a_1^2 + b_1^2)(a_2^2 +b_2^2)}}{a_2^2+b_2^2}\\
\dfrac {|z_1||z_2|}{|z_2|^2}\\
\dfrac {|z_1|}{|z_2|}$